# $12345679$ and friends

Tags: number-theory, recreational-mathematics

We can see that in the decimal system each of $12345679\times k$ $(k\in\mathbb N, k\lt 81, k\ \text{is coprime to $9$})$ (note! not $123456789$) has every number from $0$ to $9$ except one number as its digit numbers .

$$12345679\times 2=[0]24691358$$
$$12345679\times 4=[0]49382716$$
$$12345679\times 5=[0]61728395$$
$$12345679\times 7=[0]86419753$$
$$12345679\times 8=[0]98765432$$
$$12345679\times 10=123456790$$
$$\vdots$$
$$12345679\times 77=950617283$$
$$12345679\times 79=975308641$$
$$12345679\times 80=987654320$$
$$(12345679\times 82=1012345678)$$

I've been thinking about its generalization.

Here is my question.

> **Question** : Is the following proposition true?
>
> **Proposition** : Let $n\ge2\in\mathbb Z.$ For any $k\in\mathbb N$ such that $k\lt n^2$ and $k$ is coprime to $n$, if we consider
> $$[1,2,3,\cdots, (n-3),(n-2),n]_{n+1}\times k$$
> as a number with $n$-digits in base $n+1$, then it has every number from $0$ to $n$ except one number as its digit numbers, where
> $$[1,2,3,\cdots, (n-3),(n-2),n]_{n+1}$$
> represents $123\cdots(n-3)(n-2)n$ in base $n+1$.

**Example** : The examples at the top are the $n=9$ cases of the proposition.

**Remark** : Suppose that the $n$-th digit number of a number with $n-1$ digits is $0$.

For example, suppose that we treat
$$12345679\times 2=24691358$$
as
$$12345679\times 2=[0]24691358.$$

**Motivation** : I've known the followings :

$$12345679\times 9=111111111$$
$$12345679\times 18=222222222$$
$$\vdots$$
$$12345679\times 72=888888888$$
$$12345679\times 81=999999999$$

Then, I found that the property at the top has already been known.

Though I've tried to prove that the proposition is true, I'm facing difficulty. Can anyone prove or disprove it?

**P.S. $1$** :

Before I posted this question at [math overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/154254/12345679-and-friends), but it was considered as off-topic. However, I got helpful comments from S. Carnahan there.

"Isn't this just a manifestation of the base $n+1$ expansion of $1/n^2$?"

"We may assume $k\lt n$, since the addition of $j/n$ just adds copies of $j$, preserving the pattern. The progression from one digit to the next in the expansion is addition by $k$ iff the next digit has no carry, and $k+1$ iff the next digit has a carry. The symbol $n−k$ is necessarily skipped, and there is no premature periodicity (since the multiplicative order of $n+1$ mod $n^2$ is unchanged). "

I think these comments must be true, but these are not obvious for me.

**P.S. $2$** :

I'm going to write the proof for the $k\lt n$ cases to get more hints from you. This is because I'm facing difficulty for proving the following though I think the proof for the $k\lt n$ cases would be fine.

> **What I cannot prove** is : If the proposition is true for $k\lt n$, then it is true for $n\lt k\lt n^2.$

(Though this may be obvious, I cannot get a rigorous proof for it...please let me know it.)

In the following, I'm going to write **the proof for the $k\lt n$ cases**.

**Proof** : First, we use the following fact (of course, the proof is needed, but it is easy to prove it.)

Fact : $[1,2,3,\cdots,(n-3),(n-1),n]\times n=[1,1,1,\cdots, 1,1,1]$ (with $n$ $1$s)

Using this fact, we can see
$$\begin{align}[1,2,3,\cdots, (n-3),(n-2),n]\times k&=[1,1,1,\cdots,1,1,1]\div n\times k\\&=[1,1,1,\cdots,1,1,1]\times k\div n\\&=[k,k,k,\cdots,k,k,k]\div n.\end{align}$$

In the following, let us consider in mod $n$.

We can see that the remainders in the process of calculating
$$[k,k,k,\cdots,k,k,k]\div n$$
are
$$k,2k,3k,\cdots,(n-1)k,nk(\equiv 0).$$
Since $k$ is coprime to $n$, we can easily see that there is no $i\not=j\ (1\le i,j\le n-1)$ such that
$$ik\equiv jk.$$
This immediately leads that the answer for
$$[k,k,k,\cdots,k,k,k]\div n$$
has distinct numbers as its digit numbers. **Q.E.D.**

**P.S. $3$** : Now I have a question.

Can I say the following at the last step of my proof above?
I thought it was obvious, but now I feel this does not seem obvious...

"This immediately leads that the answer for
$$[k,k,k,\cdots,k,k,k]\div n$$
has distinct numbers as its digit numbers."

Comment: I provided a proof of extending your cases.

Comment: Your last step is not complete, as you prove that the remainders are distinct, but you need to prove that the digits ("quotients") are distinct. In my answer below, I show (as you did) that the remainders $r_i \equiv ik \mod n$, but then it needs a bit more work to prove that the corresponding digits $q_i$s are distinct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a proof along the lines of your agument.

Consider your special number (in your notation) 
$$S = [1, 2, 3, \dots, (n-3), (n-2), n]_{n+1}.$$ 
This number has $n$ in its units $(= (n+1)^0)$ place, $n-2$ in its $n+1$ $(= (n+1)^1)$ place, $n-3$ in its $(n+1)^2$ place, and so on, until $1$ in its $(n+1)^{n-2}$ place. So your number is 
$$S = n + \sum_{i=1}^{n-2} (n-1-i)(n+1)^i = n + \sum_{k=1}^{n-2}k(n+1)^{n-1-k} = \frac{(n+1)^n-1}{n^2} = \frac{R}{n},$$
where $R$ is defined as $nS = \dfrac{(n+1)^n - 1}{n} = [1, 1, 1, \dots, 1, 1]_{n+1}$ with $n$ $1$s. (In other words, $R$ is the [repunit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repunit) $R_n^{(n+1)}$.)

For example, for base $10$ (n = $9$), we have 
$$S = 12345679 = \dfrac{111111111}{9} = \dfrac{999999999}{9^2} = \dfrac{10^9 - 1}{9^2}.$$

---

Now that we know what our special number $S$ is, let's prove facts about it.

Consider $kS$. As $S = R/n$, we can also calculate $kS = kR/n$ by dividing $kR$ by $n$. To talk about the digits in $kR/n$, let's formalize the division procedure.

The result of dividing a number $a = [a_1, a_2, \dots, a_m]_{n+1}$ by $b$ is the quotient $[q_1, q_2, \dots, q_m]_{n+1}$ and remainder $r_m$, given by:

- $r_0 = 0$, $q_0 = 0$, and
- $q_i = \left\lfloor (r_{i-1} (n + 1) + a_i) / b \right\rfloor$ and $r_i = (r_{i-1}(n + 1) + a_i) - q_i b$ for $i = 1, 2, \dots, m$.

(Basically, $[q_1, q_2, \dots, q_i]_{n+1}$ and $r_i$ are the quotient and remainder respectively, on dividing the number formed by the first $i$ digits of $a$, by $b$.)

Now for the special case where $a = kR$ and $k < n$ and $b = n$, we have $m = n$ and $a_i = k$ for each $i$ so

- ($i=1$): $q_1 = \left\lfloor k / n \right\rfloor$ and $r_1 = k - nq_1 \equiv k \mod n$,
- ($i=2$): $q_2 = \left\lfloor (r_1(n+1) + k) / n \right\rfloor = r_1 + \left\lfloor (r_1 + k) / n \right\rfloor$, and $r_2 = r_1(n+1) + k -nq_2 \equiv r_1 + k \equiv 2k \mod n$,
  and in general, by induction
- $q_i = \left\lfloor (r_{i-1}(n+1) + k) / n \right\rfloor = r_{i-1} + \left\lfloor (r_{i-1} + k) / n \right\rfloor$, and $r_i = r_{i-1}(n+1) + k - nq_i \equiv ik \mod n$.

We'd like to prove that all $n$ $q_i$'s are distinct (when $0 < k < n$, and $k$ is relatively prime to $n$), which (as there are $n$ of them) will prove the claim that they consist of all digits $0$ to $n$ except one.

Note that the $r_i$s have already been determined: $r_i$ is the unique number in $[0, n-1)$ that is congruent to $ik$ modulo $n$, namely $r_i = ik - c_in$ where $c_i = \lfloor ik / n \rfloor$. Then, 
$$\begin{align}
q_i 
&= r_{i-1} + \left\lfloor (r_{i-1} + k) / n \right\rfloor \\
&= (i-1)k - c_{i-1}n + \left\lfloor ((i-1)k - c_{i-1}n + k) / n \right\rfloor \\
&= (i-1)k + \lfloor ik / n \rfloor - c_{i-1}(n+1) 
\end{align}$$
(Alternatively, we can calculate $q_i$ as $q_i = (r_{i-1}(n+1) + k - r_i)/n$ and get the same expression.)

As $q_i$ is a digit in base $n+1$, we know that $0 \le q_i < n+1$, so let's look at $q_i$ modulo $n+1$: from the above, 
$$q_i \equiv (i-1)k + \lfloor ik / n \rfloor \mod (n+1).$$

The distinctness of the $q_i$ thus boils down the following

> **Lemma.** $a + \lfloor a/n \rfloor \equiv b + \lfloor b/n \rfloor \mod (n+1) \iff a \equiv b \mod n$

**Proof:** Suppose $a$ has more than one digit in base $(n+1)$, say $a = \alpha(n+1) + \beta$. Then, modulo $n+1$, we have $a + \lfloor a/n \rfloor \equiv \beta + \lfloor (\alpha(n+1) + \beta)/n \rfloor = (\alpha + \beta) + \lfloor (\alpha + \beta) / n \rfloor = a' + \lfloor a'/n \rfloor$ for $a' = \alpha + \beta$. Now if $a'$ has more than one digit in base $n+1$, i.e. if $a' \ge n + 1$, we can repeat the process. By induction, $a + \lfloor a/n\rfloor$ is the same as that of the (repeated) sum of its digits (also known as [digital root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root)) which is precisely what $a \bmod n$ is (except possibly in the case when $a \bmod n = 0$, but note that $n + \lfloor n/n \rfloor = n + 1 \equiv 0 \mod (n+1)$, so that's covered as well.) $\Box$

So, if some two $q_i$ and $q_j$ are equal, we must have
$(i-1)k + \lfloor ik/n \rfloor \equiv (j-1)k + \lfloor jk/n \rfloor \mod (n+1)$, so (adding $k$ to both sides)
$ik + \lfloor ik/n \rfloor \equiv jk + \lfloor jk/n \rfloor \mod (n+1)$, which by our lemma means that $ik \equiv jk \mod n$, which in turn (when $k$ is relatively prime to $n$) means that $i \equiv j \mod n$.

This proves that the $n$ digits of $kS = kR/n$, namely $q_1$ to $q_n$, are all distinct.

(By the way, of the $n+1$ possible digits, the digit that is not attained among the $n$ $q_i$s is the one that can't appear as $(i-1)k + \lfloor ik/n \rfloor = ik + \lfloor ik/n \rfloor - k$. This is $n - k$, as $n$ is the one that can't be attained as $ik + \lfloor ik /n \rfloor$: by our lemma, if $ik \equiv c \mod n$ with $0 \le c < n$, then $ik + \lfloor ik/n \rfloor \equiv c + \lfloor c/n \rfloor \equiv c \mod (n+1)$.)

---

That does it for $k < n$, and for $n < k < n^2$, just notice that if $k = an + b$, then $kS = kR/n = aR + bR/n$. As $aR$ has all its digits equal to $a$, we have that the $i$th digit of $kS$ is congruent, modulo $n+1$, to $a$ plus the $i$th digit of $bS$. This simply corresponds to shifting all the digits by $a$, and therefore doesn't affect distinctness.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think you proved the proposition. By the way, in general, the 'removed' number is $n-k\ \text{(mod $n$)}$, isn't it?

Comment: That's right. See the  penultimate paragraph, the one that beings with "by the way"

Answer (score 4):

As the person from Math Overflow hinted, your question is best viewed in the paradigm of the base $n$ expansion of $1/(n-1)^2$.

Consider the following sum: $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k}{n^{k+1}}$. This is equal to $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{2}{n^3} + \frac{3}{n^4} + \frac{4}{n^5} + \cdots$ onward to infinity, which is in turn just equal to $\displaystyle \frac{n}{(n-1)^2}$.

The number $1n^{n-3} + 2n^{n-4} + 3n^{n-5} + \cdots + (n-3)n^1 + (n-1)$) (which is $12345679$ in base $10$) is simply this expansion multiplied by $n^{n-2}$, to produce $\displaystyle \frac{n^{n-1}}{(n-1)^2}$, and then truncating the fractional portion. So, since we're just shifting decimal places, let's look at what happens in just the case of $\displaystyle \frac{1}{(n-1)^2}$ because it's easier to work with.

In the case of $\displaystyle \frac{1}{(n-1)^2}$, the expansion in base $n$ is equal to $$ \frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{2}{n^3} + \frac{3}{n^4} + \frac{4}{n^5} + \cdots + \frac{n-1}{n^{n}} + \frac{n}{n^{n+1}} + \cdots$$

Now, here's an example of that in action in base 10:

```
0.0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 0 1 2 3 ...
  0       4       8     1 2  ...
    1       5       9     1 3 ...
      2       6     1 0        ...
        3       7     1 1       ...
```

You'll notice that the tens digit of 10 butts into the place value of the ones digit of 9, causing a carry over and increasing the value of 8 in that place to 9.

For multiples of $\displaystyle \frac{1}{(n-1)^2}$ = $\displaystyle \frac{k}{(n-1)^2}$ , the same deal applies only in multiples. For $k = 2$, for example, $\displaystyle \frac{2}{(n-1)^2}$ is just equal to:

$$ \frac{2}{n^2} + \frac{4}{n^3} + \frac{6}{n^4} + \frac{8}{n^5} + \cdots + \frac{2(n-1)}{n^{n}} + \frac{2n}{n^{n+1}} + \cdots$$

All that changes is that the numbers being added as place values go into two digits more quickly.

```
0.0 2 4 6 9 1 3 5 8 0 2 4 6 ...
  0       8     1 6     2 4  ...
    2     1 0     1 8     2 6 ...
      4     1 2     2 0        ...
        6     1 4     2 2       ...
```

Notice that the digit increases by $2$ each time now, except when the tens digit of the next number increases by $1$, in which case it increases by $3$.

Also notice that there is no $7 (= 9 - 2)$ in this expansion, just as there was no $8(= 9 - 1)$ in the first one. This is because when you try to get $7$ (e.g. with the $6$ in $16$ + the $1$ in $18$), the $2$ in $20$ butts in and forces the $7$ to carry again, increasing it to $8$.

This basically means that whenever the ones digit would become a number that's $7$ or greater, it increases by $3$ rather than $2$. But that just means that we can treat $7$ as skipped entirely, and in fact we're actually always just moving $2$ steps forward in the cyclic sequence $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9$.

And this applies in general, for $k/(n-1^2)$, we're moving $k$ steps forward in the sequence $[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, \cdots, n-1]$ with $(n - 1 - k)$ removed. This "trick" even works with numbers that aren't relatively prime to $n - 1$:

$$ 3 / 81 = 0.037037037037037... = \text{3 steps forward in } [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9] $$
$$ 9 / 81 = 0.111111111111111... = \text{9 steps forward in } [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] $$

In base 7:

$$ 2_7 / 51_7 = 0.025025025025025..._7 = \text{2 steps forward in } [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6] $$
$$ 3_7 / 51_7 = 0.040404040404040..._7 = \text{3 steps forward in } [0, 1, 2, 4, 
5, 6] $$

Keep in mind, though, that as soon as you get through the first set of $n - 1$, you go back to one step but everything in the original number sequence shifts to the right by one:

$$ 9 / 81 = 0.111111111111111... = \text{9 steps forward in } [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] $$
$$ 10 / 81 = 0.123456790123456... = \text{1 step forward in } [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 0] $$

$$ 18 / 81 = 0.222222222222222... = \text{9 steps forward in } [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1] $$
$$ 19 / 81 = 0.234567901234567... = \text{1 step forward in } [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 0, 1] $$

So the fact that all the digits except for one we removed are represented is simply a consequence of the fact that the order of $k$ in the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_{n-1}$ is still $(n-1)$ when $k$ is relatively prime to $(n-1)$.

This doesn't quite constitute a rigorous proof (mostly because I'm too lazy to formalize it and it took quite a while for me to wrap my head around what I was saying myself), but I think you have enough of an idea now that you can figure it out yourself.

---

As an additional note, it is in fact true that the multiples of $123456789$ (note! not $12345679$ which I explained above) that are relatively prime to $9$ also result in a permutation of those digits (including 0 when you reach 10 digits):

$$1 \times 123456789 = 123456789$$

$$2 \times 123456789 = 246913578$$

$$4 \times 123456789 = 493827156$$

$$5 \times 123456789 = 617283945$$

$$7 \times 123456789 = 864197523$$

$$8 \times 123456789 = 987654312$$

$$10 \times 123456789 = 1234567890$$

$$etc.$$

Well, up until 19, anyway:

$$19 \times 123456789 = 2345678991$$

---

You also asked for a proof that if the proposition holds for $k < n$, it also holds for $n \le k \le n^2$. This is actually just a simple induction, if you've already proven the $k < n$ cases.

Suppose that we have a sequence of digits $a b c d \ldots$ that contains all distinct digits except for $n - k$ in the sequence described above (i.e. the digit increases by $k$ each time now, except when it would exceed $n - k$, in which case it increases by $k+1$.).

Then increasing each digit by $1$ (as adding $n$ to the numerator will do) will mean that all the digits are still distinct, except for one that carries over to zero, increasing the previous digit by $1$. But the one immediately before it became $n - k$ upon increasing by 1, so increasing it to $n - k + 1$ means that it's still not the same as any other digits (because the one that *was* $n - k + 1$ before has since increased to $n - k + 2$). And the resulting sequence also has the property that "the digit increases by $k$ each time now, except when it would exceed $n - k$, in which case it increases by $k+1$", so the induction can continue going on.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your idea. But unfortunately I can't get a rigorous proof from your idea.